# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and Blend?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, blend

By looking at the [Visual Studio 2015 feature matrix](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs), I noticed that Blend is marked as "read-only" in Enterprise version (but fully functional in reduced Professional version). Any idea what this is about?

[image: VS Feature Matrix]

We are currently on VS 2013 Ultimate and are using integrated Blend extensively for our WPF projects. If upgrading to 2015 will prevent us from editing XAML outside text editor, that would be a rather huge showstopper. What puzzles more is that a much cheaper version of VS can do it. Makes no sense at all.

Comment: I highly suspect that the chart is wrong. Does make me wonder what it was meant to be applied to though.

Comment: If we look at a previous version of the page, for 2013, we [can see](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315030407/https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx) that footnote 2 (which applied to Blend) was "Includes Sketchflow", whereas footnote 3, "Read-only" was applied to a number of items included in the Premium product around Architecture.

Comment: So, you are thinking that someone copy/pasted the previous page and did an incomplete job of editing it?

Comment: Yes, I think it's an incomplete edit from the previous version.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I downloaded a trial version of Enterprise anyway, we'll give it a go and check to see. You can post a answer though, so I can accept it if all ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the Product Manager for Visual Studio and can safely tell you that we accidently broke the page :). Its being fixed, as everything is 1 off in the footnotes. Fix should be live today.

Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Np. Better safe than sorry :) Thanks.